# Is Rust used to write smart contract code on Ethereum?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, rust

I thought Solidity was the only programming language to write Ethereum smart contracts. Where does Rust come in in the Ethereum developer's toolkit if at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a number of programming languages used for smart contract development. `Solidity`, `Rust`, `Cairo`, `Vyper`, `Clarity` and likely many others. But Solidity is by far the most used and holds over 80% of the "market".

Rust is not used for smart contract development on `EVM blockchains` (Ethereum, Avax etc)

However some blockchains **are not** `EVM compatible` and they are using Rust instead of Solidity for smart contract development(Polkadot. Solana)